# What are the minimal conditions for this matrix to be invertible?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

Let $A>0$ be a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite (SPD) and $B$ be an $n \times m$ matrix, then form the matrix $$ C = \left[\begin{array}{cc} A & B \\ B^T & 0\end{array}\right],$$ with $0$ being the $m \times m$ null matrix. What are the conditions in order for $C$ to be invertible? Is it enough for $B$ to have full rank? Or if so, is there anything weaker?

Answer (score 2):

If $C^{-1}$ exists, and if $m=n$, then

$$C^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{0}& Q^T\\Q& - QAQ^T
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $QB=BQ=I$.

So for the case $m=n$, $B$ needs to have an inverse.

Comment: But... Consider $C$ given by the rows $(1  0  2)$, $(0 1 2)$ and $(2 2 1)$. This matrix is clearly invertible as its determinant is different than zero, and it has the exact form as above, with the null block being $1 \times 1$ and A being the $2 \times 2$ identity...

Comment: If the null block is $1 \times 1$ the third row should be $(220)$

Comment: You're right.  My answer only works for $m=n$.  Will edit $\cdots$